# Unable to search and compile regex code from each line in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a program to match regex in the file. Initial lines of my file looks as shown below

```
Alternate Take with Liz Copeland (Day 1) (12am-1am)                    
    Saturday  March 31, 2007                    
        No.    Artist    Song    Album (Label)    Comment
    buy    1    Tones on Tail    Go! (club mix)    Everything! (Beggars Banquet)    
    buy    2    Devo    (I Can't Get No) Satisfaction    Anthology: Pioneers Who Got Scalped (Warner Archives/Rhino)
```

My code to match first line of the file is as follows

```py
with open("data.csv") as my_file:
  for line in my_file:
      re_show = re.compile(r'(Alternate Take with Liz Copeland) \((.*?)\)\s\((.*?)\)')
      num_showtitle_lines_matched = 0
      m_show = re.match(re_show, line)
      bool(m_show) == 1
      if m_show:
         num_showtitle_lines_matched += 1

         show_title =  m_show.group()

print("Num show lines matched --> {}".format(num_showtitle_lines_matched))
print(show_title)
```

It should give me result as below

```
Alternate Take with Liz Copeland (Day 1) (12am-1am)
num_showtitle_lines_matched -->1
```

But my result doesn't show any output. 
Please let me know how to accomplish this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: *It should give me result as below* : which result?

Comment: @PedroLobito He didn't format, i edited it now

Comment: ok, but it's still unclear to me what you're trying to do. You're also trying to match a multi-line string when there's none (you're parsing the file line by line), try the regex on `my_file.read()`.

Comment: you missed that you set `num_showtitle_lines_matched` to `0` in the for loop
thatswhy you get the match and it is increased to 1 but in the iteration afterwards it is set back to 0

Answer (score 1):

As in the comment:
just put the `num_showtitle_lines_matched = 0` above the loop:

```python
with open("data.csv") as my_file:
  num_showtitle_lines_matched = 0
  for line in my_file:
      re_show = re.compile(r'(Alternate Take with Liz Copeland) \((.*?)\)\s\((.*?)\)')      
      m_show = re.match(re_show, line)     
      bool(m_show) == 1
      if m_show:
         num_showtitle_lines_matched += 1
         show_title =  m_show.group()
print("Num show lines matched --> {}".format(num_showtitle_lines_matched))
print(show_title)
```

Output:

```python
Num show lines matched --> 1
Alternate Take with Liz Copeland (Day 1) (12am-1am)
```

Comment: anonymous13: could you mark answers as correct and vote up? Thank you